# PHP Email To HTML issue

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to send an email with PHP but I get a weird error.

In the PHP I have:

```
<?php

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $headers, $message);

$email_to = 'example@example.com';

$email_subject = 'Hello World';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['test1']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['test2']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= '</body></html>';

   if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $headers, $message)){
        echo 'sent';    
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
?>
```

With this I receive as a plain text:

```
<html><body><table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10"><tr><td>
<strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>test@test.com</td></tr><tr><td>
<strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>hello world</td></tr></table></body></html>

From: example@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Can anyone spot what I'm I doing wrong? I tested this on 2 different servers with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up the position of the $message and $headers. Try this instead `mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: It makes no difference at all.

Comment: You put that inside your code right, inside the if statement? Did the call succeed ? Did you get a response of 'sent'?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
 if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers)){ ...
```

You've got $message and $headers in the wrong order.